# Assigning value to a pointer struct gives a segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I created a struct and a pointer of that type. I allocated memory to it using malloc but when I try to actually assign some values to it (specifically read in integers and floats from a file) it gives me a segmentation fault saying "No source available for "ungetwc() at *somelocation*"".

Here are parts of the code concerning the pointers and structs:

```
typedef struct {
    int *rain;
    float *avgtemp;
    float *avgwind;
} weather;

weather *year = (weather*) malloc(n*sizeof(weather));
if (year == NULL)
{
    return 1;
}

for (i = 0; i!=12; i++)
{
    fscanf(infile, "%i %f %f", (year+i)->rain, (year+i)->avgtemp, (year+i)->avgwind);
}
```

I thought maybe the problem was with the missing & in fscanf but when I add it my IDE gives me a warning that int* is expected but int** is provided.

Comment: You only allocated memory for the struct variable you still need to allocate memory for its pointer members.

Comment: remove `*` from all struct's members and then add `&` in fscanf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, this is what is required:

```
typedef struct {
    int *rain;
    float *avgtemp;
    float *avgwind;
} weather;

weather *years = malloc(n * sizeof(weather));
if (year == NULL) {
    return 1;
}

weather *year = years;
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i, ++year) {
    year->rain = malloc(sizeof(int));
    year->avgtemp = malloc(sizeof(float));
    year->avgwind = malloc(sizeof(float));
    fscanf(infile, "%i %f %f",
        year->rain, year->avgtemp, year->avgwind);
}
```

But, what I really think you want is to *not* use pointers *within* the `struct`:

```
typedef struct {
    int rain;
    float avgtemp;
    float avgwind;
} weather;

weather *years = malloc(n * sizeof(weather));
if (year == NULL) {
    return 1;
}

weather *year = years;
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i, ++year) {
    fscanf(infile, "%i %f %f",
        &year->rain, &year->avgtemp, &year->avgwind);
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> yes, I just removed the pointers from the struct, it did solve all the problems I had. Maybe I misunderstood what my professor said.

Maybe. The first method (i.e. *your* version) *is* valid for certain more complex use cases. For example, if the `struct` had a `char *` for a string where the string length could be arbitrarily long.

The second version is more idiomatic, and easier to work with.

Otherwise, everywhere else in your code, when accessing an element, we'd be doing (e.g.) `int rain = *year->rain;` instead of [the simpler] `int rain = year->rain;`

If one of the `struct` members needed to be an *array* of values (e.g.) the struct is for a *yearly* report and we need (e.g.) the *monthly* rainfall for each month (vs. cumulative rainfall for the year), it might be okay for `rain` to [again] be `int *rain;`. But, given this, since the number of months in a year is fixed, we could do: `int rain[12];` to keep the simplicity.

Comment: yes, I just removed the pointers from the struct, it did solve all the problems I had. Maybe I misunderstood what my professor said.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have allocated memory only for a struct, but fields of this struct are still "waiting" for address assignment. Pointers are only aliases to addresses in memory and thanks to that it is more human-readable to operate that addresses.

There are some ways to resolve your problem. I created four different functions and I used two different types of struct.

- struct with int and float pointers;
- struct with int and float fields which has already allocated memory.

**Code**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int rain;
    float avgtemp;
    float avgwind;
} weather;

typedef struct {
    int *rain;
    float *avgtemp;
    float *avgwind;
} weatherp;


/* Obtain amount of items in array (implemented in <sys/params.h> header). */
#define nitems(x)       (sizeof((x)) / sizeof((x)[0]))


/* Ex. 1: Using array of defined size. */
void
first_option()
{
        weather year[2];
        int ii;

        for (ii = 0; ii < nitems(year); ii++) {
                fscanf(stdin, "%d %f %f", &year[ii].rain, &year[ii].avgtemp, &year[ii].avgwind);
        }

        for (ii = 0; ii < nitems(year); ii++) {
                fprintf(stdout, "%d %f %f\n", year[ii].rain, year[ii].avgtemp, year[ii].avgwind);
        }    
}

/* Ex. 2: Using malloc(3). */
void
second_option()
{
        const int n = 2;
        weather *year =  (weather *)malloc(n * sizeof(weather));
        int ii;

        for (ii = 0; ii < n; ii++) {
                fscanf(stdin, "%d %f %f", &year[ii].rain, &year[ii].avgtemp, &year[ii].avgwind);
        }

        for (ii = 0; ii < n; ii++) {
                fprintf(stdout, "%d %f %f\n", year[ii].rain, year[ii].avgtemp, year[ii].avgwind);
        }

        free(year);
}

/* Ex. 3: Values in struct are pointers. */
void
third_option()
{
        const int n = 2;
        weatherp *year =  (weatherp *) malloc(n * sizeof(weatherp));
        int ii;

        for (ii = 0; ii < n; ii++) {
                year[ii].rain = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
                year[ii].avgtemp = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
                year[ii].avgwind = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float));

                fscanf(stdin, "%d %f %f", year[ii].rain, year[ii].avgtemp, year[ii].avgwind);
        }

        for (ii = 0; ii < n; ii++) {
                fprintf(stdout, "%d %f %f\n", *year[ii].rain, *year[ii].avgtemp, *year[ii].avgwind);
        }

        for (ii = 0; ii < n; ii++) {
                free(year[ii].rain);
                free(year[ii].avgtemp);
                free(year[ii].avgwind);
        }
        free(year);


 }

/* Ex. 4: Using array of defined size but struct fields are pointers. */
void
fourth_option()
{
        weatherp year[2];
        int ii;

        for (ii = 0; ii < nitems(year); ii++) {
                year[ii].rain = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
                year[ii].avgtemp = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
                year[ii].avgwind = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
                fscanf(stdin, "%d %f %f", year[ii].rain, year[ii].avgtemp, year[ii].avgwind);
        }

        for (ii = 0; ii < nitems(year); ii++) {
                fprintf(stdout, "%d %f %f\n", *year[ii].rain, *year[ii].avgtemp, *year[ii].avgwind);
        }

        for (ii = 0; ii < nitems(year); ii++) {
                free(year[ii].rain);
                free(year[ii].avgtemp);
                free(year[ii].avgwind);
        }
}


int
main()
{

        first_option();
        second_option();
        third_option();
        fourth_option();

        return (0);
}
```

In functon **first_option()** I defined two-element array of structs (defined as `weather` type). Both array and struct fields have already allocated memory because I did not use fields being pointers but instances of `int` / `float` types.

In functon **second_option()** I defined pointer which will contain instances of weather struct. Struct fields have already allocated memory because inside struct I did not use fields being pointers. There are instances of `int` / `float` types. But I must assign memory for pointer. Comparing to previous example, I do not have an array of structs so I must create it. Therefore I alloc memory for `n` instances of `weather` struct. It is like creating several (n) shelves for several data boxes (containers / structs containing some important informations).
After all, memory allocated by malloc should be freed by `free(3)` function.

In functon **third_option()** I have no defined memory both for array and struct fields. As you can see, now I used newly created `weatherp` type. In this case I must assign memory both for struct fields and also for the "shelves" for data boxes (an array). Therefore I alloc memory for `n` instances of `weatherp` struct and then, before using `fscanf(3)` I assign memory for every struct field separately. After all, memory allocated by `malloc(3)` should be freed by using `free(3)` (every struct field and at the end -- container for struct instances).

Last function **fourth_option()** defined two-element array of structs (defined as `weather` type) but fields of struct do not have allocated memory. Therefore, before using `fscanf(3)` I assign memory for every struct field separately. After all, memory allocated by `malloc(3)` should be freed by using `free(3)`.

***Some additional info:***

Every address for variables declared like `int a;`, `struct type name;` or `char tab[10];` have already dynamically allocated memory on a stack and this memory is "freed" automatically after the end of function. Space allocated manually (e.g. using `malloc(3)`) is allocated on a heap until calling `free(3)` function. Nowadays operating system kernels after the end of program can free manually allocated memory but it is good practice eliminate memory leaks and it shows that you are aware of what you are doing.

PS. During tests, I replaced amount of month from 12 to 2 and I read data from `stdin`, not from file. And of course, we should check things like successfull function execution (e.g. if pointer after `malloc(3)` call is not `NULL`). I just did not want to complicate a code.